# How to get api data from nodejs app to appear on react frontend with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

From my front-end, I am attempting to get data from the backend running at port 5000. I am not sure if the port is supposed to be running before running the react app. However, I tried both situations, I ran the backend port 5000 on a different terminal, and then the frontend on a different terminal. Do I actually use a request or response with the get method for axios? Please, is there anything wrong with my code?

**This is my frontend**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

const Quotes = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState("");
function getQuote(){
    axios.get("https://localhost:5000/", { crossdomain: true }).then(response => {
    setText(response.data.text);
    setAuthor(response.data.author);
});
}
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={getQuote}> Generate Quote</button>
            <h1>{text}</h1>
            <h3>{"-" + author}</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Quotes;
```

So, over here, I am attempting to send API data with express to the homepage. And I am struggling to understand why it is not appearing on the front-end.

**This is my backend**

```
const express = require("express");
const quote = require('inspirational-quotes');

const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });

app.get("/", function(req, res){ // quotes is send to the homepage of app
    res.send(quote.getQuote());
});

let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == ""){
    port = 5000;
}
app.listen(port, () =>{
    console.log("Server is running...");
});
```

I get the data when I run the backend on port 5000, but I don't get it to display on the react app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my bug. I had to debug it from the browser console. I realized I used `https` for localhost. It was the wrong URL protocol.

I corrected it by changing `https://localhost:5000/` to `http://localhost:5000/`